# How to disable the warning about unapproved verbs when importing modules?

Tags: powershell

When importing a module with `Import-Module` I get the following warning:

> WARNING: Some imported command names include unapproved verbs which might make them less discoverable. Use the Verbose parameter for more detail or type `Get-Verb` to see the list of approved verbs.

How can I disable it?

Comment: for any powershell command try `help <command name>` from the prompt.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Use `-DisableNameChecking` as in

```
Import-Module -DisableNameChecking
```

Quoting the [Import-Module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/import-module) documentation:

> **-DisableNameChecking**
>
> Indicates that this cmdlet suppresses the message that warns you when
> you import a cmdlet or function whose name includes an unapproved verb
> or a prohibited character.
>
> By default, when a module that you import exports cmdlets or functions
> that have unapproved verbs in their names, PowerShell displays the
> following warning message:
>
> "WARNING: Some imported command names include unapproved verbs which
> might make them less discoverable. Use the Verbose parameter for more
> detail or type `Get-Verb` to see the list of approved verbs."
>
> This message is only a warning. The complete module is still imported,
> including the non-conforming commands. Although the message is
> displayed to module users, the naming problem should be fixed by the
> module author.

Answer (score 0):

I think the missing information here is to ask yourself:

> *What do they mean with **"unapproved verbs"**?*

It's quite simple, but only when you know it.

Any module that that is imported that contains (new) functions that are name in the following way:
`<word1>-<word2>`
where each of the 2 words cannot be found in the *allowed* list from `Get-Verb` [1], and are connected with a dash (`-`).

To circumvent the problem, you have 3 options:

1. Rename all you functions to **not** have any dash (`-`) in their names.
2. Rename all you functions to start with one of the words in [1].
3. Import your module with the `-DisableNameChecking`.